# XCode 8 / Sierra - black screen after splashscreen when testing with Testflight, Simulator / run via cable works fine

Tags: xcode, testflight

I have a strange problem!

I'm using Xcode 8 / Sierra. When I test my app in the simulator or run it on my iPhone everything works fine. But when I archive the build and upload it - and try to test it via test flight, I just see the splash screen and then everything is black.

Have someone experienced this before? Someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch from test flight, the launch options are not nil and if you havent handled this case, the view will not load.

```
if launchOptions != nil && launchOptions?.count != 0 {
        do{
          if let notification =  launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let aps = notification["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
            let redirect_url = notification["redirect_link"] as! String
            setRootVC()

            }
            else{
               throw EncryptionError.Exception
              }
            }
            catch{
                setRootVC()
            }
        }
        else{
            setRootVC()
         }
```

Comment: so where should i copy this... My problem is at TestFlight, i am stacking at black screen. Simulator is fine , running on device fine.. i even check @ionic/react capacitor documents if i missed something